# jQuery anchor to a button won't work on WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, frontend

I have a button that gives search results but i have no control over it from the frontend i want it to scroll down once clicked on the button. i added this code but it wont work . this is the link to the page http://gymjoe.ca/gyms/ .. its the search now button . below the code i used i created an id for the anchor at bottom of the page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn btn-default a").click(function() {
        $.scrollTo('#ancfoot', 800, {easing:'elasout'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any anchor named `ancfoot` in your code, however I have two ways how to fix this for you.

First of all, your button has the classes `btn` and `btn-default`, there is no `a` tag. So your selector is wrong and should be like so: `$('.btn.btn-default')`.

1) Currently your form is submitted when clicking on the search button. If you don't want to submit it and if you will fetch the form values through JavaScript (for AJAX, DOM manipulation, ...) you will need `.preventDefault()`. This will stop the form from submitting.

This will look like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn.btn-default").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.scrollTo('#ancfoot', 800, {easing:'elasout'});
    });
});
```

2) If you need the form to be submitted for the search, you probably won't need any JavaScript. Appending the anchor to the `action` attribute of your form should do it, like so:

```
<form action="http://gymjoe.ca/gyms/#ancfoot" role="form" id="form-map" class="form-map form-search" method="GET">
    <!-- your form --->
</form>
```